# Combine two ffmpeg commands (segment and still photo)

Tags: ffmpeg

is it possible to combine this command

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -map 0:s:0? -c copy -movflags empty_moov+default_base_moof+frag_keyframe -f segment output%03d.mp4
```

with a command that can take a still from the first segment

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00.00 -i output001.mp4 -vframes 1 -q:v 2 still.jpg"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append the second command to the first:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -map 0:s:0? -c copy -movflags empty_moov+default_base_moof+frag_keyframe -f segment output%03d.mp4 -frames:v 1 -q:v 2 still.jpg
```